# Draw graph wherein vertices are ArrayPlots

Tags: plotting, graphs-and-networks

I need to place `ArrayPlot` in the vertices of graph. i.e. in graph

```
 Graph[{1->2, 2->3, 3->1}]
```

I have to replace vertex 1 with `ArrayPlot[{{0,0,1}}]` and so on based on the following list

```
{{1,{0,0,1}},{2,{0,1,0}},{3,{1,1,0}}}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
r := RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 10}]; 
Graph[{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 1}, 
   VertexShape -> {1 -> ArrayPlot[r], 2 -> ArrayPlot[r],  3 -> ArrayPlot[r]}, 
   VertexSize -> Medium]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I think it is a bit closer than bill's answer

```
r = {{1, {0, 0, 1}}, {2, {0, 1, 0}}, {3, {1, 1, 0}}};

Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1}, 
  VertexShape -> (# -> ArrayPlot[{#2}, PlotRangePadding -> 0] & @@@ r),
    VertexSize -> {0.3, 0.1}]
```

[image]

Comment: It would be nice to have the edge arrows touch the boxes, but I could not come up with a reasonable method... I hope you don't mind my edit!

Comment: @IstvánZachar The method turn out to be very simple. Thanks for nice editing!

Comment: Ha, that is indeed simple! (I was fiddling with the offset of `Arrow`)

Answer (score 5):

I thought you may adopt this neat Demonstration by Stephen Wolfram. You can download the source code notebook right there where the link points, but the code is so small I gave it here too. Note the cool trick - when graph becomes too large, vertices become dots - may come handy.

[Cellular Automaton State Transition Diagrams](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/CellularAutomatonStateTransitionDiagrams/)

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 If[icon, Labeled[#, 
     Grid[{Column[
          Map[ArrayPlot[{#}, Mesh -> True, Frame -> False, 
             ImageSize -> 8 Length[#]] &, #], Center, 
          Spacings -> .025] & /@ 
        Thread[{Tuples[{1, 0}, 3], List /@ IntegerDigits[rn, 2, 8]}]},
       Frame -> All, FrameStyle -> GrayLevel[1/GoldenRatio]]], #] &[
  GraphPlot[# -> CellularAutomaton[rn, #] & /@ Tuples[{1, 0}, w], 
   ImageSize -> {500, 375}, 
   VertexRenderingFunction -> (With[{p = {Darker[Blue, .7], 
          Point[#]}}, 
       If[! label, p, 
        If[w < 7, 
         Inset[ArrayPlot[{#2}, Mesh -> True, Frame -> False, 
           ImageSize -> 7 { Length[#2], 1}], #], 
         Tooltip[p, 
          Dynamic[ArrayPlot[{#2}, Mesh -> True, Frame -> False, 
            ImageSize -> 7 { Length[#2], 1}]]]]]] &), 
   DirectedEdges -> True]], {{rn, 110, "rule number"}, 0, 255, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{w, 5, "width"}, 3, 12, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, Delimiter,
 {{label, If[w < 7, True, False], "show states"}, {True, False}},
 {{icon, False, "show rule icon"}, {True, False}}, 
 AutorunSequencing -> {{1, 20}, {3, 5}}, SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use ArrayPlot as vertices.

```
Graph[{ArrayPlot[{{0, 0, 1}}] -> ArrayPlot[{{0, 1, 0}}], 
  ArrayPlot[{{0, 1, 0}}] -> ArrayPlot[{{1, 1, 0}}], 
  ArrayPlot[{{1, 1, 0}}] -> ArrayPlot[{{0, 0, 1}}]}]
```

or replace vertices:

```
r = {{1, {0, 0, 1}}, {2, {0, 1, 0}}, {3, {1, 1, 0}}};
g = VertexReplace[Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1}], Rule[#, ArrayPlot[{#2}]] & @@@ r]
```

Comment: Your first code fits me well too, but unfortunately it does not work ((

Comment: @Филипп Цветков what do you mean by it does not work? If you mean by the output, you could do this: Graph[{ArrayPlot[{{0, 0, 1}}] -> ArrayPlot[{{0, 1, 0}}], 
  ArrayPlot[{{0, 1, 0}}] -> ArrayPlot[{{1, 1, 0}}], 
  ArrayPlot[{{1, 1, 0}}] -> ArrayPlot[{{0, 0, 1}}]}, 
 VertexShapeFunction -> "Name", VertexSize -> Medium]